# CompositDisposable is not lazy enough?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, idisposable

I was surprised that the reactive extension `CompositeDisposable` class failed the following test

```
[Test]
public void TestDisposable()
{
    var ds = new List<IDisposable>();
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    using (new CompositeDisposable(ds))
    {
        ds.Add(Disposable.Create(() => a[0] = 3));
        ds.Add(Disposable.Create(() => a[2] = 1));
    }
    Assert.That(a[0],Is.EqualTo(3)); //Failed here
    Assert.That(a[1], Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(a[2], Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

So this means if I create a `CompositeDisposable` by given a `IEnumerable<IDisposable>` it actually iterates all its elements, rather than defer this to the `Dispose` being called.

This might be useful in other cases, but in mine it is inconvenient. Are there any other classes that can to the above easilier?

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of `CompositeDisposable` will make a copy of your list. So, when you add elements to the list afterwards, they will not be used by the `CompositeDisposable`.

Here's a simple solution:

```
using (var composite = new CompositeDisposable())
{
    composite.Add(Disposable.Create(() => a[0] = 3));
    composite.Add(Disposable.Create(() => a[2] = 1));
}
```

Or, if that's not convenient, here's a workaround:

```
public static IDisposable AsLazyComposite(this IEnumerable<IDisposable> sequence)
{
    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        foreach (var disposable in sequence)
            disposable.Dispose();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
using (ds.AsLazyComposite())
```